# Get count of +1 of a webpage in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, google-plus, google-plus-one

I want a method to get a webpage url and return count of it's +1. I searched google and just find [this](http://johndyer.name/getting-counts-for-twitter-links-facebook-likesshares-and-google-1-plusones-in-c-or-php/) and the method is:

```
int GetPlusOnes(string url) 
{

     string googleApiUrl = "https://clients6.google.com/rpc"; //?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ";

     string postData = @"[{""method"":""pos.plusones.get"",""id"":""p"",""params"":{""nolog"":true,""id"":""" + url + @""",""source"":""widget"",""userId"":""@viewer"",""groupId"":""@self""},""jsonrpc"":""2.0"",""key"":""p"",""apiVersion"":""v1""}]";

     System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(googleApiUrl);
     request.Method = "POST";
     request.ContentType = "application/json-rpc";
     request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

     System.IO.Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream();
     UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
     byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
     writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     writeStream.Close();

     System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
     System.IO.StreamReader readStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
     string jsonString = readStream.ReadToEnd();

     readStream.Close();
     responseStream.Close();
     response.Close();

    var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(jsonString);
    int count = Int32.Parse(json[0]["result"]["metadata"]["globalCounts"]["count"].ToString().Replace(".0", ""));

    return count;
}
```

but there is an error in

```
var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(jsonString);
```

because the `Deserialize` method gets two arguments and I don't know the second argument.
does anybody know what is the second argument or know another methods that works fine?

**update**
I also tried

```
    public static Regex REGEX_GETURLCOUNT =
    new Regex(@"<div[^>]+id=""aggregateCount""[^>]+>(\d*)</div>");

    public int GetPlusOnes(string url)
    {
        string fetchUrl =
            "https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=" +
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url) + "&count=true";
        WebClient wc=new WebClient();
        string response = wc.DownloadString(fetchUrl);

        Match match = REGEX_GETURLCOUNT.Match(response);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

but `match.Success` is always `false`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to do something like this recently, i used:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int test = GetPlusOnes("http://www.allfancydress.com/"); //Returns 11 plus ones
            Response.Write("Plus ones: " + test.ToString());
        }

        public static Regex REGEX_GETURLCOUNT =
         new Regex(@"<div[^>]+id=""aggregateCount""[^>]+>(\d*)</div>");

        public static int GetPlusOnes(string url)
        {
            string fetchUrl =
                "https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=" +
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url) + "&count=true";
            HttpWebRequest request =
                (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fetchUrl);
            string response = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse()
                .GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            Match match = REGEX_GETURLCOUNT.Match(response);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                return int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
            }
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps

*edited out my custom proxy class, you can just cut and paste this and it will work for you.

Comment: I have `using System.Web;` but there isn't any `HttpUtility` there!

Comment: Well that's where it lives, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx

Comment: what is `gp` in line : `string response = gp.Request(fetchUrl);`?

Comment: 'gp' is a class i created to Generate a new Proxy, the 'Request' method takes a url and then does it's request behind a proxy. You'll obviously have to modify this code slightly but everything you need is right there.

Comment: ok. but in the code `if (match.Success)` always returns `false`!

Comment: Your 'string response' needs to be 'new StreamReader(request.GetResponse()
                .GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();'. I'll edit my answer, this definitely works, having just tested it.

Comment: No, your implementation of it is `false`. Do you have the correct using statements? `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;`

Comment: What do you mean by `false`? Maybe the url you're querying doesn't have any plus ones on it? That's the only other thing i can think of... Cut and paste the exact code into a fresh ASP.net app and see for yourself...

Comment: I debugged the code. the response that I downloaded using `WebClient` is ok and contains the +1.  I removed the `if` line and change the next line of it to `return int.Parse(match.Groups[0].Value);` and I got an exception that says `match.Groups[0].Value` isn't an int value and I get it and it was this: <div id=\"aggregateCount\" class=\"t1\">113k</div>. it means all the download process works correct but the `regex` doesn't do correctly. It's all things I understood.

Comment: Why would you remove the `if` statement? The above version works fine as it is. Out of curiosity, what's the url you're running this against?

Comment: the url is `https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=http://google.com` and I removed `if` to check what happens if there was no `if`

Comment: You're checking for plus ones on google.com? Lol... If this has answered your question, please mark it as the answer, thanks.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, you're running it against google.com which doesn't have a Google+ 1 one button on it... You are also missing 'www.' from your url, thus, it `returns 0;`, run it on a page that actually contains a plus one button. E.g. `http://www.allfancydress.com/`

Comment: go and check it. Google has 113k +1's.